# Android JNI: Getting backtrace from remote device

Tags: android, java-native-interface, logcat, stack-trace, crash-reports

How can i get a stack trace from a device in case of a crash in native library?

I want to email it to myself, but i can't find a way to get this information in the application. I can see the backtrace and other information when i type "adb logcat" but if i run logcat from the application, i cannot get the same information, long story short, "i cannot see my own crash report with logcat". I believe this is a relatively new thing that an application can only see the logs it has written itself.

So there are thousands of people who writes native library for android, how do they get the report and backtrace if their native code crashes?

Thank you.

Comment: You could try integrating something like crashlytics to catch/report crashes.

Comment: Thanks Buddy, it seems more complicated than i expected, but i will definitely give it a try.